# C++ to Java - эквивалент функции swap

Tags: java, c++

Какой аналог функции `swap` в C++ `std::vector`

А именно:

```
vector1.swap( vector2 );
```

В Java в качестве `vector` я использую `ArrayList`.

Comment: Если опишете, что делает сей код в плюсах будет проще.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, [вот описание с примером](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap-free/)

Comment: Код

    ArrayList temp = vector1;
    vector1 = vector2;
    vector2 = temp;

делает в первом приближении то, что вы написали. Или вам обязательно обменять содержимое, а не ссылки? Расскажите о своей настоящей задаче.

Comment: @VladD, насколько понимаю в C++ swap так и делают. 

А вот как в Java реализуются итераторы и останутся ли они valid после обмена -- это вопрос.

Comment: @avp: Тонкость в том, что если у кого-то был указатель на `vector1`, то после `swap` для него будет выглядеть, что контент изменился.

В Java насчёт валидности итераторов ([отсюда](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html)):

> Note that `Iterator.remove` is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress.

Comment: А в документации к ArrayList https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#listIterator(int) утверждается, что iterator сломается только при структурных изменениях (добавление, удаление элементов). Таким образом, если размеры списков одинаковы, то можно провести swap поэлементно, и iterator останется рабочим. Изменение элемента не является структурным изменением.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно поменять содержимое двух объектов `ArrayList` без изменения их ссылок - то можно поменять именно это содержимое, используя доступ к полям данного типа, где хронятся нужные нам данные. Только нужно не забыть поменять размер, хранящийся отдельно.

```
void swap(ArrayList<?> list1, ArrayList<?> list2) {
    try {
        // Swap data
        Field elementDataField = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("elementData");
        elementDataField.setAccessible(true);
        Object stored = elementDataField.get(list1);
        elementDataField.set(list1, elementDataField.get(list2));
        elementDataField.set(list2, stored);

        // Swap sizes
        Field sizeField = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("size");
        sizeField.setAccessible(true);
        int size = sizeField.getInt(list1);
        sizeField.setInt(list1, sizeField.getInt(list2));
        sizeField.setInt(list2, size);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignored
    }
}
```

После этого можно использовать данный метод в своём коде, например, следующим образом:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list3x100 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(100, 100, 100));
ArrayList<Integer> list5x200 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(200, 200, 200, 200, 200));

// list3x100: 100, 100, 100
// list5x200: 200, 200, 200, 200, 200

swap(list3x100, list5x200);

// list3x100: 200, 200, 200, 200, 200
// list5x200: 100, 100, 100
```

Надеюсь, это поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю **самописный** вариант функции основанный на `System.arraycopy(Object src, int pos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`:

```
public static void swap(List<?> list1, List<?> list2) {
    List<?> tmp;
    System.arraycopy(list1, 0, tmp, 0, list1.length);
    System.arraycopy(list2, 0, list1, 0, list1.length);
    System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, list2, 0, list2.length);
}
```